# Render JSON into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I get JSON data with next code:

```
$.getJSON(
     "data.json",function foo(result) {
       $.each(result[1].data.children.slice(0, 10),
        function (i, post) {
          $("#content").append( '<br> HTML <br>' + post.data.body_html );       
        }
      )
    }
 )

 <div id="content"></div>
```

Some of strings included : `&lt;` and `&gt;` and this did not displaying as regular html `<`, `>`
Try to use `.html()` instead `.append()`  did not work.

Here is live example http://jsfiddle.net/u6yUN/

Comment: Can you paste your response controlle/function ?

Comment: I updated and forked your live example. I have posted my results:  [***Jump to Answer***](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21184942/1762224)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is whet you were asking for: <kbd>[Complete JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/gWcse/)</kbd>

```
var jsonRequestUrl = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/1v6rrq.json';
var decoder = $('<div />');
var decodedText = '';

$.getJSON(jsonRequestUrl, function foo(result) {
    var elements = result[1].data.children.slice(0, 10);

    $.each(elements, function (index, value) {
        decoder.html(value.data.body_html);
        decodedText += decoder.text();
    });

    $('#content').append(decodedText);
});
```

---

**Edit**: Keeping this here as a simpler example.

```
// Encoded html
var encoded = '&lt;div style="background:#FF0"&gt;Hello World&lt;/div&gt;';

// Temp div to render html internally
var decode = $('<div />').html(encoded).text();

// Add rendered html to DOM
$('#output').append(decode);
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/RLdQ4/)</kbd>

Answer (score 9):

Just use the 3rd (`space`) parameter of [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to format the json, and use `<pre>` tags to display.

```js
const json = { foo: { bar: 'hello' } }


$('html').append('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(json, null, 2) + '</pre>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a nice collapsible render I've written a module to this. It's in pure JavaScript so you can use it in any framework.

[mohsen1/json-formatter-js](https://github.com/mohsen1/json-formatter-js)

It's also available as an AngularJS directive if you are using AngularJS
[mohsen1/json-formatter](https://github.com/mohsen1/json-formatter)

Checkout the demo here: [AngularJS directive demo](http://azimi.me/json-formatter/demo/demo.html)

It's also theme-able, so you can change the colors:
[image: normal]
[image: dark]

Answer (score 4):

Another library that works for rendering JSON objects is: [renderjson](https://github.com/caldwell/renderjson)

Although it has a minimalistic style, it allows to click through the JSON structure.

Example usage:

```
document.getElementById("test").appendChild (renderjson (data));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to give [JSON2HTML](http://json2html.com/) a try. Works with native JavaScript, with jQuery and with node.js. Allows to completely customize the generated HTML.

Comment: I tried it. I just want to render the JSON structure , I don't want to define or customize anything. Example usage for this library: `var transform = {'<>':'div','text':'${name} (${age})'}; var data = [ {'name':'Bob','age':40}, {'name':'Frank','age':15}, {'name':'Bill','age':65}, {'name':'Robert','age':24} ]; document.write( json2html.transform(data,transform) );` What I would expect is: `document.write (json2html (data));` , however this library doesn't have this feature apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.parseHTML()` jQuery `method`

```
var myData = "yourHtml with &lt;" //

$("#content").append($.parseHTML(myData));
```

Here it is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x4haw/

Comment: I think he wants actual html?

Comment: It's ambiguos, i think \:

Comment: why you should do all this operations? I don't understand the question, maybe

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way is

```
var t= post.data.body_html;
t.replace('&lt','<').replace('&gt', '>');
$("#content").append( '<br> HTML <br>' + t );
```

Comment: I tried `.replace()` before butrhis did not work for me too, can you try to add this to my example at http://jsfiddle.net/u6yUN/

Answer (score 0):

try this way...

```
var htmlString = $("<div/>").html(data).text();
```