# JSON API call how do I parse from the response to a html page

Tags: ajax, json

I am trying to create a web page based on a JSON call.

https://app.citizenspace.com/api/2.3/json_consultation_details?dept=parliament&id=ddcengage&fields=all

The Request in the URL generates a JSON response, I am trying to parse the response to HTML with this code to generate the URLs for the 'Related Links' section.

I am a total newby to rendering out JSON to HTML if anyone can provide any examples that would be most appreciated.

Comment: You are missing 1 piece. A HTML template. Use the data to fill the "template spots" of the HTML template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render JSON into HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184733/render-json-into-html)

Comment: I think I am struggling with the following.

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$.getJSON ('https://app.citizenspace.com/api/2.3/json_consultation_details?dept=parliament&id=ddcengage&fields=all'), function(data) {

consol.log(data.interests)


}

</script>