# Partial rendering on AJAX call in Play Framework

Tags: java, javascript, playframework, playframework-2.3, twirl

I saw some similar questions here but none of them actually helped to solve my issue.

I have a table on the page and a button that needs to rerender the table on click(using different pagination parameters, sorting, etc).

I tried several approaches, and I succeed in passing the values to the controller with embedded js router but since the values are passed to the backend with an ajax call I'm not able to rerender the table.

My embedded router looks like:

```
@helper.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
    routes.javascript.UserController.getUsers
)
```

And I will call it from the page with something like:
$.ajax(jsRoutes.controllers.UserController.getUsers(3, true, "login"));

Now, last but not least, I want to rerender the table with the result from getUsers() call.

Simply calling:

```
public Result getUsers(int size, boolean isAsc, String sortBy) {
    ......
    Logger.info("Returning " + size + " users");
    return Results.ok(usersPage.render(userDtos));
}
```

doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is several approaches.

The simplest is to have a play controller which render the table in HTML, then pull it on your page using [$('#mytable').load(...)](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

The more flexible is to have a play controller which return data in [JSON format](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaJsonActions), then convert it to HTML in the browser. This can be done by hand, using a client-side template engine ( http://handlebarsjs.com/ for instance) or using a complete javascript framework (like AngularJS or Ember.js).

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. Can you be more specific about second approach? Returning HTML is not an option for me. As for templating, I'd rather stick to the build-in twirl template engine, but it's not my main concern. Can you provide an example of how you would render the HTML client side by hand when the action is called with ajax?

Comment: Why can't you return HTML ? Really it's just a fragment of HTML (a table in your case), this fragment update a node of the DOM. You don't have a full page refresh.
The JSON approach implies rendering HTML in JavaScript, you can't do that with Twirl.

Comment: Here two examples of client-side "manual" rendering : http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/sEwM6/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184733/render-json-into-html
If your table is complex you should really use a template engine or a complete framework.

Comment: I don't want to return HTML fragment because in my case it can be quite big(the table has a "More" button that expands it further down, so we can be talking about hundreds of rows). Moreover, I don't know if it will help because what difference does it make what content I try to render? The problem is nothing is re-rendered even though the data sent to render() method is updated. All this stuff was really easy to do in  JSF using region, for example. I'm new to Play yet I'm sure there must be some simple mechanism for partial re-rendering. This requirement is simply ubiquitous nowadays.

Comment: JSF is an old school. What happens in a partial rendering you think? A ajax call happens behind the scene and JSF's client side js replace the returned html. In play there is no unnecessary abstractions which hide the essentials that happen under. You do it with your hand.

Comment: Why do you choose Play Framework over JSF ? JSF is a component oriented framework, while Play Framework is request oriented. They have very different sweet spots. Also, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework#Push-based_vs._pull-based

Comment: I wanted to experiment with a web-framework without Servlet API and, additionally, we use Akka extensively and since Play is also Akka-based, it is very convenient to glue different backend components together using reactive approach.